# Assign / cast more specific type of IEnumerable<object> not working with structs

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

Why can I not do this:

```
public Form1() {
    IEnumerable<int> longEnum = new List<int>();
    IEnumerable<object> objEnum = longEnum; // <-- Compiler error
}
```

...but I can do this?

```
public Form1() {
    IEnumerable<Form1> formEnum = new List<Form1>();
    IEnumerable<object> objEnum = formEnum;
}
```

My guess would be that it has to do with the fact that `int` is a struct, while `Form1` is a class.

I have a function that will return `IEnumerable<object>` where it's *actual* type may be something much more specific that I don't know at compile time. I.e.

```
public interface IEnumFetcher{
    IEnumerable<object> GetEnumeration{ get; }
}

public class EnumGetter1 : IEnumFetcher {
    public IEnumerable<object> GetEnumeration() {
        get { return new List<long>() ;} // <-- Doesn't compile
    }
}

public class EnumGetter2 : IEnumFetcher {
    public IEnumerable<object> GetEnumeration() {
        get { return new List<string>() ;} // <-- Compiles just fine!
    }
}

public class Form1{
    public Form1(){
        var getter1 = new EnumGetter1();
        var getter2 = new EnumGetter2();

        var getting1Result = getter1.GetEnumeration();
        var getting2Result = getter2.GetEnumeration();
    }
}
```

**Now... the more important question, is how can I achieve what I'm looking to do?**

Comment: @shree.pat18, int is a struct: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RyanGriffith Apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, variance only works for reference types. From [Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx):

> Variance is supported only if a type parameter is a reference type. Variance is not supported for value types.

And from the C# Spec, 13.1.3.2 Variance Conversion:

> A type `T<A1, …, An>` is variance-convertible to a type `T<B1, …, Bn>` if T is either an interface or a delegate 
>   type declared with the variant type parameters `T<X1, …, Xn>`, and for each variant type parameter Xi one of the 
>   following holds:
>
> - Xi is covariant and an implicit reference or identity conversion exists from Ai to Bi
> - Xi is contravariant and an implicit reference or identity conversion exists from Bi to Ai
> - Xi is invariant and an identity conversion exists from Ai to Bi

Note that there is not implicit reference or identity conversion between any value type and `object`. There's only a boxing conversion.

**Reason why**

The thing is, `T<A>` can only be convertible to `T<B>` if the compiler can prove that `T<A>` can be accessed in the same exact way as `T<B>` without having to change the IL to make it work.

If either `A` or `B` are value types, then the two generic types are not convertible, since the compiler would possibly have to introduce boxing/unboxing instructions.